# Commission Junction Daily Publisher Commission Service

Tags: php, soap, commission-junction

I am creating a website with the Commission Junction links,. Now I need to process the commission reports for dividing the commissions. I am planning to use  Daily Publisher Commission Service as it provides a provision for including the date in the request. Now I am not able to do a purchase through the CJ link and so I am using a sample query that has given in [CJ site itself](http://help.cj.com/en/web_services/Example_Queries_Daily_Publisher_Commission.htm). I am new to these wbservices and so have some doubts here.

1. The actual respone will be exactly same as the one given. I mean will it includes the `<soapenv:Envelope` 
   things or it is begin with just the ns1.???
2. I have assigned the response to a variable $result and give

   $result_xml=simplexml_load_string($result);

but it is showing the error that ns1 is not defined in namespace. Then I have given the  `<soapenv:Envelope`  things to the top. Now the error has gone. But the result_xml variable is blank .

Please help me if someone has done it before. or please suggest me some good tutorials so that I can learn and do it. It will be much helpful if someone can give the complete sample response and so I can check the code with it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML response to a SOAP request will be something like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <findPublisherCommissionsResponse xmlns="http://api.cj.com">
            <out xmlns="http://api.cj.com">
                <publisherCommissions xmlns="http://transaction.service.cj.com">
                    <ns1:PublisherCommissionV2 xmlns:ns1="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                        <actionStatus xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            closed
                        </actionStatus>
                        <actionType xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            sale
                        </actionType>
                        <adId xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            13123123
                        </adId>
                        <advertiserId xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            12312312
                        </advertiserId>
                        <advertiserName xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            Merchant UK ltd
                        </advertiserName>
                        <commissionAmount xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            25
                        </commissionAmount>
                        <country xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                        </country>
                        <eventDate xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            2009-08-28T20:30:44-07:00
                        </eventDate>
                        <lockingDate xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            2009-09-10T00:00:00-07:00
                        </lockingDate>
                        <orderId xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            1231232
                        </orderId>
                        <original xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            true
                        </original>
                        <originalActionId xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            12312321312
                        </originalActionId>
                        <postingDate xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            2009-08-28T23:30:03-07:00
                        </postingDate>
                        <sId xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            googlelink
                        </sId>
                        <saleAmount xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            25
                        </saleAmount>
                        <transactionId xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            123123123
                        </transactionId>
                        <websiteId xmlns="http://transaction.domain.cj.com">
                            1231231
                        </websiteId>
                    </ns1:PublisherCommissionV2>
                </publisherCommissions>
                <sortBy xmlns="http://transaction.service.cj.com">
                </sortBy>
                <totalResults xmlns="http://transaction.service.cj.com">
                    1
                </totalResults>
            </out>
        </findPublisherCommissionsResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

You maybe having issues parse the xml response into a SimpleXml Object because SimpleXML doesn't like colons (:) in the tag and attribute names [SOAP & SimpleXML](http://dd32.id.au/2007/09/29/php-simplexml-soap/). Also check here [SimpleXML & Namespaces](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2005/10/20/simplexml-and-namespaces/)

Your SOAP request should already be an object so I am uncertain as to why you are trying to parse it using SimpleXML.  If you need the response as XML then you could always use a [serializer](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer).

In my own script as an example I use something like this:

//code here
 $cj_devkey = "CJ KEY HERE";

```
        $ini    = ini_set( "soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0" );
        $client = new SoapClient( "https://pubcommission.api.cj.com/wsdl/version2/publisherCommissionServiceV2.wsdl", array(
             'trace' => true,
            'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
            'proxy_host' => "proxy" 
        ) );

        $object = $client->findPublisherCommissions( array(
             "developerKey" => $cj_devkey,
            "date" => '08/28/2009',
            "dateType" => 'event',
            "advertiserIds" => '',
            "websiteIds" => '123456',
            "actionStatus" => '',
            "actionTypes" => 'sale',
            "adIds" => '',
            "countries" => 'all',
            "correctionStatus" => 'all',
            "sortBy" => '',
            "sortOrder" => '' 
        ) );
```

A sample response using print_r($object) will return :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [out] => stdClass Object
        (
            [publisherCommissions] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [PublisherCommissionV2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [actionStatus] => closed
                            [actionType] => sale
                            [adId] => 123123213
                            [advertiserId] => 2313531
                            [advertiserName] => MERCHANT HERE
                            [commissionAmount] => 25
                            [country] => 
                            [eventDate] => 2009-08-28T20:30:44-07:00
                            [lockingDate] => 2009-09-10T00:00:00-07:00
                            [orderId] => 123123
                            [original] => 1
                            [originalActionId] => 123123
                            [postingDate] => 2009-08-28T23:30:03-07:00
                            [sId] => sports
                            [saleAmount] => 25
                            [transactionId] => 12312312
                            [websiteId] => 123123
                        )

                )

            [sortBy] => 
            [totalResults] => 1
        )

)
```

If you want to traverse the object elements you can use stuff like:

```
$num_results = $object->out->totalResults;
```

or loop through each commission payment with stuff like:

```
foreach ( $object->out->publisherCommissions as $commission ) {
                $user_id        = $commission->{'sId'};
                $transaction_id = $commission->{'transactionId'};
                $program_id     = $commission->{'advertiserId'};
                $post_date      = $commission->{'postingDate'};
                $action_status  = $commission->{'actionStatus'};
                $amount         = $commission->{'commissionAmount'};
}
```